# Sorting user input and printing out in same category

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, printing

My homework is to work with a 2-dimensional array to receive console input of the number of hours each employee (8 total) has worked in a 7 day week. I'm then to total up all the input and then print out the totals of each employee in descending order.

I've been able to figure out how to print out the user inputs in descending order, only, I don't know how to print them out to their corresponding employee #.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ComputingWeeklyHours {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[][] register = new int[8][7];
        System.out.println("Enter hours for each employee");
        for (int i = 0; i < register.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < register[i].length; j++){
                System.out.printf("Employee %d:", i+1);
                register[i][j] = in.nextInt();
            }
        int[] totaledHours = sum(register);
        Arrays.sort(totaledHours);
        for (int k = totaledHours.length-1; k >= 0; k--){
            System.out.print(totaledHours[k] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static int[] sum(int[][] total){
        int[] totaled = new int[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < total.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < total[i].length; j++)
                totaled[i] += total[i][j];
    return totaled;
    }
}
```

This prints out everything in descending order.

So how can I associate each index with the employee #?

Comment: One row for an employee?

Comment: can you give an example of input and output?

Comment: @xbit, yeah one row per employee.

Comment: Input  for only 3 employees: employee 1:0,0,0,8,8,8,0 employee2: 0,8,8,8,8,0,0.  Employee 3: 0,0,0,0,8,8,0. Output : employee 2: 32, employee 1: 24, employee 3: 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by employee# you mean the order in which the employee details are entered, you could use an inner class to store the employee details as the employee number and his total hours as shown below.

```
class Employee{
    int employeeNo;
    int totalHours;
}
```

and then modify the sum() method to store an array of employee objects instead of an array of int(which can only store one int). Here is how you could change the sum method as below

```
public static Employee[] sum(int[][] total){
    Employee[] totaled = new Employee[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < total.length; i++)
        Employee[i].employeeNo = i+1;
        for (int j = 0; j < total[i].length; j++)
            Employee[i].totalHours += total[i][j];
return totaled;
}
```

Comment: I haven't learned objects yet but that's the topic for this week so I may be able to implement this soon.

Comment: In that case, if you would like to implement just using int arrays, you could define a two dimensional totaled array in your sum() mehthod as int[8][2]. The 8 employees will have two values each, first the employee number and second the totaled hours. Try to modify the sum() method to implement this approach.

Comment: Sounds easy. I feel I could get the values into the 2d array but I'm not sure how I would go about sorting it.

Comment: Well, since you need to sort the hours and retain the corresponding the employee numbers, you could store the total hours in a separate array along with storing it in the multi-dimensional array and sort that array using the built-in method and use a loop to compare the values of the sorted array with the other one and print it accordingly. Or, if you are interested in learning sorting algorithms, you could read up on it and implement your own sorting method. You can find a lot of sorting implementations in the net, so you could also download one of them and try modifying them.